# Oggy and the cockroaches

Tags: soundtrack

Ok so, ive been looking for 5 months for the oggy and the cockroaches season 1 and season 2 soundtrack, so far no luck, i mean the movie soundtrack is there but that one sucks, someone please help.

> Oggy and the Cockroaches (known as Oggy et les Cafards in French) is a French comedy animated television series produced by Gaumont Multimedia (first two seasons) and Xilam Animation (third season onwards), and created by Jean-Yves Raimbaud. The show employs silent comedy: characters either do not speak, or use unintelligible vocalizations and gestures; the Indian version of the show has Hindi dialogue dubbed over the animation. When the show started airing in 1998, it was successful in France and was eventually broadcast worldwide.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oggy_and_the_Cockroaches

Answer (score 1):

[This CD](https://www.discogs.com/Various-Oggy-Et-Les-Cafards-Le-Show-Du-Chat/release/5204254) seems to be what you are looking for.

I cannot guarantee this music comes directly from the cartoon soundtrack (except from first and last tracks) since it looks like a derived product (it is in the ["adaptation" section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oggy_and_the_Cockroaches#Adaptations) on Wikipedia). But it is clearly not the [movie soundtrack](https://musicbrainz.org/release/e07ac0af-03c8-47f8-8ba1-a3ac363d3359) you mentioned.

Wikipedia tells us this music was also released on music streaming sites in 2010, but as of now the [20-track digital version](https://oggyandthecockroaches.fandom.com/wiki/Oggy_et_les_Cafards:_Le_Show_du_Chat) is not available anymore (even in this [user playlist](https://www.deezer.com/fr/playlist/54873195) on Deezer, album tracks are mostly grayed out in my country).

Nevertheless, all is not lost as you can listen to the tracks that are not named "interlude" through [this YouTube account](https://www.youtube.com/user/NHarmonik/videos).

Comment: I can add that the music from season 1 to 4 is written by Hugues Le Bars and Hervé Lavandier according to Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oggy_and_the_Cockroaches.